# selecting from a table that got an n:n relation to another table with an argument checked in the second table

Tags: sql, select

I got something like the following Table structure

```
table a
Int id primary key
String description

table b
Int id primary key
some fields...

table ab (as a linking table because the table a and b have a n:n relation)
Int id primary key
int bid foreign key to b.id
int aid foreign key to a.id
```

How can I select every `b` that's linked with an `a` that's description is `'Test'`?

Right now I'm working with this method (really slow)

first i select the id of a with

```
select id from a
where description = 'Test';
```

then i take all id's from b that are linked in the table ab into an list

```
select bid from ab
where aid = id;
```

and last i select them one by one inside a for loop with this query

```
select * from b
where id = id;
```

so how can I improve this?
thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tag your question with the sql provider you are using.

Anyways, something like this:

```
select b.*
from a join ab on a.id = ab.aid join b on ab.bid = b.id
where a.description = 'TEST';
```

Comment: I didn't want to tag it because we are using several different SQL provider and this was more a general question but thx for your answer